# How to handle a custom date format coming from json data with angularjs?

Tags: json, rest, date, angularjs

I have a angularjs service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Scheduler', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/scheduler/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
        'get' :{method:'GET', isArray:false},
        'save' :{method:'PUT'}
    });
})
```

which returns the following json:

```
{
    'start': '08:00:00',
    'end': '21:30:00',
    'offset': 5
}
```

Is there e preferred way in angularjs to convert the 'start date' and the 'end date' in a js Date Object and back to a string right before 'save' it back to the webservice?

Some kind of function which is called right before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it not supported by the `$resource` service at the moment, use the $http instead. With `$http` you can have request and response transformers.